# php excel formula field returning 0

Tags: php, odbc, phpexcel

I am using `PHPExcel_1.8.0_`, just reading from a file and margin it to another field

all working fine but got problem with the formula fields  .. its returns 0 for any formula field

my code can one tell me how to get the value rather than 0

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($full_file_withputh);
            $this->objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($full_file_withputh);
            $row_number=$this->opobj->start_row;
if(isset($this->opobj->dataset))   {unset($this->opobj->dataset);}
$this->opobj->dataset[$counter][$col_number]=$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_number,$row_number)->getValue();
```

I have also tried

```
 $this->opobj->dataset[$counter][$col_number]=$this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_number,$row_number)->getCalculatedValue();
```

but it not worked

Comment: You need to give us a little more information... Can you give an example of a formula that's failing? [Some features aren't supported](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/430505) by the PHPExcel engine...

Comment: What is the formula in this cell? And what are the values of the referenced cells?

Comment: it is simple text but it is fetching from different sheet

Comment: What is the actual value returned by your call to `getValue()`? This should be a string containing the actual formula: if that is returning a `0`, then `getCalculatedValue()` will certainly return a `0` as well.... if you call `getDataType()` for that cell, you should get a "f" back to indicate formula, and the value in the cell (retrieved via `getValue()`) should have a '=' as the first character

Comment: first one is ='Planning Stage '!J3 and that field is referring   =IFERROR(I9,"") now i was trying to fetch that cell with getCalculatedValue() but no differance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks all for the support ....
as i have tried several ways and didn't get the result i am looking for ... so i have changed the the way of reading the file ... their i used php odbc for reading the file

```
    $excelFile = realpath($full_file_withputh);
    $excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
    $result = odbc_exec ($connection, "select * from [sheet$] ");

    $row = odbc_fetch_array($result)
```

it by default takes the first row as Field name

and its worked

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project making use of PHPExcel and ran into many such problems. After going through the docs, I figured the I would get expected values if I used following code

```
$field_value = $this->objPHPExcel
                   ->getActiveSheet(0)
                   ->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_number,$row_number)
                   ->getFormattedValue();

if($field_value == null) {
    $field_value = $this->objPHPExcel
                       ->getActiveSheet(0)
                       ->getCellByColumnAndRow($col_number,$row_number)
                       ->getOldCalculatedValue();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks but getFormattedValue is not working with me/my version so i used value